# Type relation between two modules built by functors

Tags: types, module, ocaml, functor

I have defined several signatures and modules as follows:

```
module type MATRIX =
sig
  type 'a t
  val init: 'a -> 'a t
end

module type MMM =
sig
  type 'a t
end

module type AMATRIX =
sig
  include MATRIX
  module Mmm : MMM
  module Matrix: MATRIX
  val mmm_of_amatrix: 'a t -> int -> int -> 'a Mmm.t
end

module type AREAMMM =
sig
  type t
  module Mmm: MMM
  val make: int Mmm.t -> t
end

module MatrixArray: MATRIX =
struct
  type 'a t = 'a array array
  let init (e: 'a) : 'a t = failwith "to do"
end

module MmmArray: MMM =
struct
  type 'a t = 'a array array
end
```

And two functors:

```
module AMatrixFun: functor (Mmm: MMM) -> functor (Matrix: MATRIX) -> AMATRIX
  with
    module Mmm = Mmm
  and
    module Matrix = Matrix =
      functor (Mmm: MMM) -> functor (Matrix: MATRIX) ->
    struct
      include MatrixArray
      module Mmm = Mmm
      module Matrix = Matrix
      let mmm_of_amatrix (m: 'a t) (nr_i: int) (nc_i: int) : 'a Mmm.t = failwith "to do"
    end

module AreaMmmFun : functor (Mmm: MMM) -> AREAMMM
  with module Mmm = Mmm =
    functor (Mmm: MMM) ->
  struct
    type t
    module Mmm = Mmm
    let make (x: int Mmm.t) : t = failwith "to do"
  end
```

And applied functors with some modules:

```
module AMatrix  = AMatrixFun(MmmArray)(MatrixArray)
module AreaMmm  = AreaMmmFun(MmmArray)

let a = AMatrix.mmm_of_amatrix (AMatrix.init 5) 0 0
let b = AreaMmm.make a
```

The compilation works fine on this piece of code. However, if I change the last part to

```
module AMatrix : AMATRIX = AMatrixFun(MmmArray)(MatrixArray)
module AreaMmm : AREAMMM = AreaMmmFun(MmmArray)

let a = AMatrix.mmm_of_amatrix (AMatrix.init 5) 0 0
let b = AreaMmm.make a
```

the compilation stops at the last line, and gives me:

```
File "lib/tools.ml", line 69, characters 21-22:
Error: This expression has type int AMatrix.Mmm.t
       but an expression was expected of type int AreaMmm.Mmm.t
```

I really want to add `: AMATRIX` to `AMatrix` and `: AREAMMM` to `AreaMmm`, because that ensures me that these two modules are constrained with these two signatures. Could anyone help?

Comment: Again, same question as in the other thread: what problem are you trying to solve. Please use words instead of code. Your code seems overly complicated to me in order to do trivial things, so please try to explain what is your problem clearly if you want to have some help.

Comment: Well, the aim of my code is really not trivial, and it is difficult to explain its concrete meaning like this... So it is normal that the implementation looks complicated... But I think the technical  problem of the code is understandable for whom know well functors and modules...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application *needs* to know that `AMatrix.Mmm.t` is the same as `AreaMmm.Mmm.t`, because otherwise you will not be able to use values created by one module in functions provided by the other module.

As I previously explained, if you assert that `module AMatrix : AMATRIX` then you are throwing away any additional information about the contents of `AMatrix` that is not contained in `AMATRIX`. In particular, since `AMATRIX` does not mention that `AMatrix.Mmm.t` is the same as `AreaMmm.Mmm.t`, that information is lost and the code does not compile.

What you should assert instead is that:

```
module AMatrix : AMATRIX 
  with module Mmm = MmmArray 
   and module Matrix = MatrixArray
```

Answer (score 3):

I have still no idea of what you try to achieve, but if your goal is to implement some kind of inheritance between you modules (as you said in some previous thread title), you may need to use recursive modules.

So for instance, you start by defining your module hierarchy: here `S` is the initial module signature, which can extended by `S1` and `S2`:

```
module type S = sig
  type 'a t
end

module type S1 = sig
  include S
  val f: 'a -> 'a t
end

module type S2 = sig
  include S
  val g: 'a t -> 'a
end
```

Then, you create your concrete implementation, which define exactly what is `'a t`, and which implements all the functions needed by both `S1` and `S2`:

```
module Concrete = struct
  type 'a t = 'a array
  let f a = [| a |] (* fill with the right contents *)
  let g a = a.(0)   (* fill with the right contents *)
end
```

Then, you abstract the type `'a t` away by constraining the implementation with the right signatures. You need recursive modules here (note the `rec` keyword):

```
module rec I : S = Concrete
and I2 : S2 with type 'a t = 'a I.t = Concrete
and I1 : S1 with type 'a t = 'a I.t = Concrete
```

And you can test your result:

```
let a = I2.g (I1.f 0)
```

which returns `0` as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what if I want to force the type in `I1` and `I2` to `int array`? I have changed `type 'a t = 'a array` in `Concrete` to `'a t = int array`, but it does not work...

Comment: Well you can't do that directly, because `I1` satisfies signature `S1`. `'a I1.t` (where `t` is abstract) cannot be unified with `int array`. However, you can define an alias `type tt = int I1.t` and use the alias `tt` in your signature if you wish, but you cannot replace `I1.t` by `array` as it would break abstraction: what if someone else implements a concrete implementation of `S` using lists for instance ?